# HTTP 401 after TLS is established

Tags: wcf, authentication

I'm calling a WCF web service on JBoss over HTTPS. I don't think it matters but I use a smart card to authenticate (certificate is copied in personal store). When I call the web service function I get prompted for smart card's PIN code, and then I get `MessageSecurityException` with message

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.

Inner exception is WebException, with message:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

If I use Internet Explorer I can get wsdl on appropriate https URL. Any idea on what's happening?

EDIT: Using [Fiddler](https://www.fiddler2.com) I can see that TLS channel is being established with return code 200, but on subsequent function call the Apache server returns

> HTTP/1.1 401 Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials

Comment: Without looking at the WCF service config file, you'll get mostly guesses. Seems like your client app isn't sending the correct soap headers in its request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the case of user access management. When the user of mentioned smart card was added to the server's list of users allowed to call the web service the problem was solved.